# PyQt crashes when emitting QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5

I'm emitting model through a signal from non-GUI thread to GUI thread in order to create QTableView and set the model. Unfortunately, app crashes. When I'm emitting dictionaries and prepare model in diagram class just before setting QTableView, everyhing works. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python 3.4 and PyQt 5.4.1.

Here is the code snippet:

```
class CheckNE(QObject):

    #some code ...

    neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged = pyqtSignal(QStandardItemModel, QStandardItemModel)

    def check_bts_envalms(self, modelEnvBscAlm):  # i call it from other CheckNE member function

        #some code, i'm creating modelEnvBtsAlm here...

        print('Before emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged')
        self.neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged.emit(modelEnvBtsAlm, modelEnvBscAlm)
        print('After emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    #some code ...

    @pyqtSlot(QStandardItemModel, QStandardItemModel)
    def retrieveTreeForEnvAlm(self, modelBtsEnv, modelBscEnv):
        print('Receiving neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged')

        dialogTableWorker = TableDialog(modelBtsEnv, modelBscEnv)
        print('Before showing dialog')
        dialogTableWorker.show_table_dialog()
        print('After showing dialog')


class TableDialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog_Table):
    def __init__(self, modelBts, modelBsc):
        print('Beginning init of TableDialog')
        super(TableDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(modelBts)  # tableView created in Qt Designer
        print('Ending init of TableDialog')

    def show_table_dialog(self):
        print('Showing TableDialog started')
        self.exec_()
        print('Showing TableDialog ended')


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow()
    checkNeWorker = CheckNE()
    checkNeWorkerThread = QThread()

    main_window.show()
    main_window.raise_()

    checkNeWorker.moveToThread(checkNeWorkerThread)
    checkNeWorker.neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged.connect(main_window.retrieveTreeForEnvAlm)
    checkNeWorkerThread.start()

    app.exec_()

main()
```

Result:

```
Before emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged
After emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

But when I'm debugging with breakpoint in line:

```
print('Before emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged')
```

Everything works like a charm:

```
Before emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged
Receiving neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged
Beginning init of TableDialog
After emitting neTreeForEnvAlmsChanged
Ending init of TableDialog
Before showing dialog
Showing TableDialog started
Showing TableDialog ended
After showing dialog
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by emitting a QStandardItemModel?

Comment: I want to process data in worker thread, create model from it and show it in a view, which should be created in GUI thread.

Comment: [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) is a QtGui class, which means is it **not** thread-safe.

Comment: So am I forced to emit some data container instead, e.g. list or dict and set up model in gui thread?

Comment: @lazare. Only if you choose to use `QStandardItemModel`. If you wrote a [custom model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) as a wrapper for the `dict/list`, you wouldn't need to emit any data - you could just emit a simple notification signal from the worker thread, which would trigger [layoutChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged) in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the types when you declare the signal and the slots since they are not python types but they are defined at C++ level. As the documentation says: *the types that define the C++ signature of the signal. Each type may be a Python type object or a string that is the name of a C++ type.*

```
pyqtSignal('QStandardItemModel', 'QStandardItemModel')
```

and

```
@pyqtSlot('QStandardItemModel', 'QStandardItemModel')
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, after that change nothing happens - slot is not triggered.

Comment: The type of `QStandardItemModel` is `QtCore.pyqtWrapperType`. So it **is** a python type. The only reason for using strings is to specify C++ types that are *not* wrapped by pyqt (e.g. `QString` in pyqt5).

Comment: I suggested this solution because I have the same problem while emitting a signal with a `QGraphicsItem` as argument. If I remove the quoted around the argument type my application crashed badly.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone. `QGraphicsItem` is an abstract C++ class (i.e. it can't be instantiated in python), so that probably explains why it causes a crash.